# Roblox Lua Humanoid:Move

Tags: lua, roblox

Pardon the noob question, I am new to Roblox LUA.

I am trying to make the humanoid move forwards and backwards, (as when an officer, guards a perimeter by moving to and fro) but there may be something wrong with this script, because it only moves forwards.

```
local toggle = true
local RunService = game:GetService("RunService")
local humanoid = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")

RunService:BindToRenderStep("Move", Enum.RenderPriority.Character.Value + 1, function()
   while toggle do
       humanoid:Move(Vector3.new(0, 0, -1), true)
       wait(1)
       humanoid:Move(Vector3.new(0, 0, 1), true)
       wait(1)
   end
end)
```

And then when I toggle = false, it does not stop.

I can't use keypress as it defeats the purpose of what I intend to do.

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way this code is structured does not make much sense. You're creating a loop inside a function that is triggered every frame. Every single frame, you create a new loop... After just 10 seconds you might have 300 loops trying to move the humanoid at the same time.

Because the loops constantly overwrite each other, the last one to run takes precedence... Which is likely why it's only towards one direction.

I presume you want to make the character move towards (0,0,-1) for a second, then towards (0,0,1) for another second and then, if toggle is enabled, run again.

What you should be doing instead is not creating a loop inside the BindToRenderStep, but setting the movement every frame according to where the character should be moving to, and running that loop outside, once:

```lua
local toggle = true
local RunService = game:GetService("RunService")
local humanoid = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")

movement = nil

RunService:BindToRenderStep("Move", Enum.RenderPriority.Character.Value + 1, function()
   if movement then
       humanoid:Move(movement, true)
   end
end)

while toggle do
    movement = Vector3.new(0, 0, -1)
    task.wait(1)
    movement = Vector3.new(0, 0, 1)
    task.wait(1)
end
movement = nil
```

Mind that this code has some quirks:

- Nothing will be able to run after the while, so nothing will realistically set the toggle off if placed after `while toggle do`. It depends on where you want to switch the toggle how you'd handle this.
- Depending on where you've placed this, it might error. If this is in StarterPlayerScripts you should use the CharacterAdded event to wait until the character exists, and then handle setting the humanoid again when respawning (because the humanoid will not be the same one if the character respawns). If this is in StarterCharacterScripts, there is no need to access the LocalPlayer, you can just do `script.Parent:WaitForChild("Humanoid")` (though it also comes down to personal preference).
- You've made the movement relative to the camera with that `true` argument to `:Move()` https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Humanoid#Move. The player will still be able to move the camera to change how the movement direction.

Comment: Aimarekin, the script did not work, at first, it moved forwards only. but my golly, the script and clear logic explanation you provided helped me understand the character movement even more.

By placing 'movement =' in each vector, I was able to make the humanoid move whichever way.

Thank you so much for imparting your knowledge my good man!

Comment: @PaulCrevase Oh I see why it didn't change directions, I forgot to add `movement = Vector3.new(0,0,1)` in the loop when I create the second vector. I corrected the answer, but glad to hear it worked

Comment: Thanks @Aimarekin.

When I set the toggle = false, it does not stop. Would you have an idea how to unbind it?

I tried UnbindToRenderStep, but it did not work.